# About non-normal nilpotent subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, nilpotent-groups

Suppose that all non-normal abelian subgroups of a finite group $G$ are cyclic. What can I say about non-normal nilpotent subgroups of $G$?
Is it true that such supgroups are cyclic?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: What do you mean by non-normal abelian subgroups?

Comment: The first claim is not true. There are abelian subgroups which are not normal and also not cyclic.

Comment: @DietrichBurde It is a hypothesis. $G$ is a finite group in which all non-normal abelian subgroups are cyclic.

Comment: Are you assuming that some particular group $G$ has the property that every non-normal abelian subgroup of $G$ is cyclic or are you claiming that this is true for all finite groups?

Comment: Ah, I am sorry. Let me change my answer then.

Comment: @the_fox I assume that there exists a group with such properties.

Comment: @AmanPandey Abelian subgroups which are not normal subgroups of $G$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The finite p-groups all of whose non-normal abelian subgroups are cyclic have been classified -see [here](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0219498813500527).
I would think that among these $p$-groups we should find a counterexample.

What about the generalized quaternion  group $Q_{32}$, where we know that all abelian subgroups are cyclic, and the nilpotent subgroup $Q_8$ is not normal and not cyclic? See [here](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/1/Q32.html).

Comment: Have you searched this site? If it is not a duplicate you could post it as a new question.

Comment: @A-213 Check out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3689206/about-finite-group-such-that-zg-must-be-cyclic

Comment: @NickyHekster Thank you for your help. It seems that these posts belong together.

Comment: @NickyHekster Thank you so much. It seems that my question is a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, so the lesson learned, as Dietrich pointed out, first browse this site before posting something. But, I admit, sometimes things are difficult to find. Keep asking questions anyway!

Comment: @DietrichBurde I am sorry but it seems that my question is a duplicate. Thank you so much for your time and your answer.

Comment: @NickyHekster I had searched it from google but it could not find that. Can I delete my question?

Comment: No do not delete it. If you ask a question on this Math Stack Exchange site - not using Google - then possible earlier posts will be suggested according to your key words in the title (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Another way to look for something here is using the "magnifying glass" bar at the top of this page.

Comment: @NickyHekster Thank you so much.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I edited my question and accepted your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If All non-normal nilpotent subgroups of a group G are cyclic, then all non-normal abelian subgroups of G are cyclic. But the converse is not true. As an example, generalized Quaternion group of orders greater than 16.  The Quaternion type groups contain two non-normal cyclic subgroups of order 4,  and other non-normal subgroups are non-abelian of the Quaternion type.

The structure of finite groups whose non-normal nilpotent subgroups are cyclic are characterized and can see in the following paper.

H. Mousavi and G. Tiemouri, Structure of finite groups with trait of non-normal subgroups, Communications in Algebra, Vol. 47, No. 3, (2019).

The structure of finite groups whose non-normal abelian subgroups are cyclic are characterized and can see in the following conference paper.

English Booklet (Vol 1) of 51st Annual Iranian Mathematics Conference, (119-122).