# Let $G$ be a non-nilpotent group where all the non-normal abelian subgroups of $G$ are cyclic. Then $G$ has cyclic center.

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, sylow-theory

> Theorem : Let $G$ be a non-nilpotent group such that all the non-normal abelian subgroups of $G$ are cyclic. Then $G$ has cyclic center.

Proof. Suppose that $Z(G)$ is non-cyclic. since $G$ is non-nilpotent, then there exists some $P \in \mathcal{S} y \ell_{p}(G)$ such that $P \ntriangleleft G$. Then $Z(G)$ has a subgroup $\left\langle z_{1}, z_{2}\right\rangle$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{q} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q},$ for some prime $(p \neq) q \in \pi(G) .$ since $\left\langle z_{1}, z_{2}, P\right\rangle \ntriangleleft G$ is abelian , then $\left\langle z_{1}, z_{2}, P\right\rangle$ is cyclic, which is a contradiction. Therefore $Z(G)$ is cyclic.

I can't understand why  $Z(G)$ has a subgroup $\left\langle z_{1}, z_{2}\right\rangle$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{q} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q} ? ,$ for some prime $(p \neq) q \in \pi(G) $ . why $p \neq q $ ? Why  $\left\langle z_{1}, z_{2}, P\right\rangle \ntriangleleft G$? because $P \ntriangleleft G$ ? and how we can show $\left\langle z_{1}, z_{2}, P\right\rangle $ is abelian? I think proof of theorem is wrong.

Comment: Where did this proof come from?

Comment: @verret . My teacher .

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3689206/about-finite-group-such-that-zg-must-be-cyclic is relevant

Comment: Yes I agree, the proof is wrong. No explanation is given for $q \ne p$, and there is no reason why $P$ should be abelian. I beleive that the proof that I gave in answer to your earlier question is correct.